# 850hPa temp Advection Example Not Working

Tags: python-siphon

I am new to plotting and examining wx data using python. I started with this example [850 hPa temp advection](https://unidata.github.io/python-gallery/examples/850hPa_Temperature_Advection.html) and its failing at this statement.

```
ncss = NCSS('{}{dt:%Y%m}/{dt:%Y%m%d}/gfsanl_4_{dt:%Y%m%d}_'
            '{dt:%H}00_000.grb2'.format(base_url, dt=dt))
```

which gives me the following errors in a jupyter notebook. Seems to be related to XML. Perhaps the data structure of the file being used has changed since this example was created. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\users\martbar\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3326, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "<ipython-input-18-1457913792bc>", line 7, in <module>
    '{dt:%H}00_000.grb2'.format(base_url, dt=dt))

  File "C:\users\martbar\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\siphon\http_util.py", line 379, in __init__
    self._get_metadata()

  File "C:\users\martbar\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\siphon\ncss.py", line 58, in _get_metadata
    root = ET.fromstring(meta_xml)

  File "C:\users\martbar\anaconda3\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1316, in XML
    return parser.close()

  File "<string>", line unknown
ParseError: no element found: line 1, column 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because that URL is out-of-date. NCEI has updated their TDS URLs for model output from `https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/thredds/ncss/grid/<product>/` to `.../thredds/ncss/model-<product>/` and in the case of historical datasets, `.../model-<product>-old/`. So in this case, your correct `base_url` would be `https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/thredds/ncss/model-gfs-g4-anl-files-old/`

Important follow-up note, that `python-gallery` example collection has been retired and so is out of date. The more up-to-date gallery is available at the [Unidata Python Training website](https://unidata.github.io/python-training/), though the NCEI TDS URLs throughout that site are currently out-of-date as well. Hopefully for not much longer!